# UV Warp problem

Tags: uv

I'm trying to use UV warp to rig 2D eyes onto a 3D model. When I use UV warp, it warps the entire model's textures instead of around eyes, where I want it to be. What do I do?

I've made a UV map, assigned the materials, made sure the UV warp was set to the eyes' armature and target and base bones. (Done in Blender Render mode)

Answer (score 1):

You constrain the UV Warp modifier only to a section of the mesh that you want (eyes) with vertex groups.

You will need 1 vertex group for each of your eyes and 1 UW Warp modifier per eye if you would want to control them independently.